# OpenCV error for reading a video file with python 2.7

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video, video-processing

When I use `cap=cv2.VideoCapture('L1.mp4')` to read a video, it gives the below error. This error is only thrown for *some* videos. Any suggestions please?

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('L1.mp4')
_,img=cap.read()
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
fgmask = fgbg.apply(img)
fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0) in
>   cv::Mat::locateROI, file
>   C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp,
>   line 949 1 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\py_work\lipclips\PlotBox\may17.py", line 109, in 
>       fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) cv2.error:
>   C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:949:
>   error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function cv::Mat::locateROI
>
> warning: Error opening file
>   (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779) warning:
>   L1.mp4 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)

Comment: Please edit your post with enough code to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can't just extract `fgmask` from a `BackgroundSubtractor` with only one image. In this case, your `fgmask` is empty and you can't apply `morphologyEx`. Try:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('L1.mp4')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(img)

    # check if fgmask is valid
    if fgmask is None:
        continue

    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

Comment: i am using kernal like; `kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(4,4))` when it change to `kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(1,1))` that error gone.